# How to fetch newly created object from PHObjectPlaceholder after change request completes

Tags: swift, ios9, phasset

I'm using the new Photos framework and I'm saving a video to my photo roll:

```
   let assetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(url)
    assetPlaceHolder = assetRequest?.placeholderForCreatedAsset
```

A short time later in my success handler after the video has been saved to the photo library I can reference the `assetPlaceHolder` object and it's looking like a valid `PHObjectPlaceholder` object. I'm just unsure from looking at Apple's documentation how to get at the actual video or url to the video that's been saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is untested, but it pretty much works like this:

```
let assets:PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers([assetPlaceHolder!.localIdentifier], options: nil)

if let asset = assets.firstObject as? PHAsset {
     PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestPlayerItemForVideo(asset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: {
        (result, info) in
        //result: AVplayerItem?

}
```